# What are the advantages and disadvantages of associated types in protocols vs true generic protocols?

Tags: swift, generics

Swift for example only supportsassociated types in protocols, but you cannot make a truly generic protocol.
It there any backgroud theory, which is better and when and why?
Could you explain which would be better for solving a given problem, is swift were to support both?

Comment: I've marked this duplicate because I think this is what you really mean by "truly generic." As matt notes, protocols are generic. What you may be asking, without realizing it, is "why is there no generalized existential," (which would allow types like `Collection where .Element == String`), and the answer to that is "because it's complicated to implement with several tricky corner cases and hasn't been done yet, but probably will be someday."

Comment: What you really want to read is this: https://forums.swift.org/t/improving-the-ui-of-generics/22814